# Storing date in m-dimension of PostGIS geometries

Tags: postgis, geometry, date

Do you know if it is possible to assign a date (whatever the format) as the 4th dimension to a geometry in PostGIS? If so, does it recognize it as a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to store time in the m-value.

No, it cannot be a date type. It has to be numeric.

I've used unixtime, e.g. in https://anitagraser.com/2017/10/15/movement-data-in-gis-9-trajectory-data-models/. It's all based on PostGIS' temporal support, e.g. https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidTrajectory.html

(You can find more examples in https://anitagraser.com/2018/04/16/movement-data-in-gis-12-why-you-should-be-using-postgis-trajectories/)

Comment: It has to be stored as the same type as the x/y?  I.e. it can't be integer? (Been wondering this, it's that way in R's sf.)

Comment: @mdsumner `SELECT ST_M(ST_MakePointM(-71.1, 42.3, 10::integer));` does not throw an error but it returns a double precision